# Proving $\frac{\sqrt2}{2} < \sin \frac{4\pi}{15} < \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{60}$

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, inequality

I have to prove :

$$\frac{\sqrt2}{2} < \sin \frac{4\pi}{15} < \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{60}$$

I tried to decompose the sine but I do not find the way to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by mean value theorem, $$\sin(\pi/4 + \pi/60) = \sin( \pi/4) + \pi/60\cos(t), \pi/4 < t < \pi/4 + \pi/60 $$ if you use the fact $\cos(t) \le 1$ and $\sin $ is increasing on $[0, \pi/2]$ should give you the inequality you want.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{4\pi}{15} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{60}$$

Answer (score 2):

The sine function is increasing and concave over $[0,\pi/2]$. Since
$$\frac{4\pi}{15}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{60}$$
and $\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, the LHS inequality is trivial and the RHS inequality follows from the Lagrange's theorem:
$$ \sin\frac{4\pi}{15}-\sin\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{60}\cos(\xi)<\frac{\pi}{60}. $$